# Why UseLegacyPathHandling not working in UTC?

Tags: .net-4.6.2

.Net 4.6.2 has a known breaking change. Path.GetDirectoryName no longer works with URI's. However for existing code which already uses this method, it breaks. 
There is a workaround provided by Microsoft. We can add following config entry in runtime `<AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling=true"/>`

UseLegacyPathHandling runtime switch supposed to allow existing code to work. It does work when I am running the application normally. However if same code block is executed in a Unit Test, it fails. 
e.g.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName("file://localhost/etc/fstab");
    }
}


[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestClass]
public class TestClass1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestUrl()
    {

         System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName("file://localhost/etc/fstab");
    }
}
```

In above code if I run the program directly then `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName("file://localhost/etc/fstab");` statement runs fine. However if I run the unit test case then it fails. Why is it behaving like this?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this issue??

Comment: We were using Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase for getting the path and that was directly used in Path.GetDirectoryName method. Following changes fixed that issue       string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;  
        UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
        string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);